# Eliminate space characters before commas in case of multiple users flags on the same post

Tags: support, bug, flags, moderator-tools, localization

On mod dashboard when there are multiple flags on the same post I noticed the undesirable space characters before commas (after timestamps):

> [image]

I was able to find only [generic templates](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=422b5a748829f252c) for such case:

> $modPrefix$$flaggerLinks$ and $extraUsersCount$ other users$spanStart$; added $totalCommentCount$ comments$voteTypesText$$spanEnd$

But there are no commas at all. It seems that they are hard-coded somewhere inside `$modPrefix$$flaggerLinks$`. I would like to improve translation (eliminate unnecessary spaces), but can't find the source strings those are used to build full phrase.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes have anything to do with Russian text, as you have plenty of upvoted questions with similar screenshots. I think it's a combination of (a) it's not clear from the screenshot what the problem is, and (b) cosmetic issues like too much white space before a comma are about 6,000 items down on my list of things I'd like the developers to work on.

Comment: Yes, this is also the case on English sites. It is not limited to sites using translations. I've updated your post with a screenshot from SO. I have a userscript that [fixes this by inserting line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynVwL.png), which also makes it much easier scan the list of flagger names (there are some other changes, too, like highlighting the flag text and toning down the visual noisiness of the buttons).